# Loop variable confusion

Tags: python, new-operator

```
prices = [250, 20, 30]

total = 0
for price in prices:
    total += price
print(total)
```

I was told that using a variable like I did with prices in a for loop makes it a loop variable, however what I'm confused on is if the variable makes every item within the prices list a separate item. Would each item within the list now be attached to the loop variable price separately? From the research I've done it feels like it does.

The code above is a prime example. To me it feels as though it took each item that was in the prices list and attached itself onto the price variable then was able to add all of them together to get the total. If this isn't the case, can you explain what using a variable like that does?

Comment: This might be interesting: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Every item in `prices` is *already* a separate element. All the `for` loop does is assign the name `price` to each of them in succession, executing the body of the loop in between assignments.

Answer (score 0):

A list is an "iterable" object. It means you can iterate over it's entities within a for loop, assigning the value of that entity to your iterator ("loop variable" how you call it)

The iterator would get the value of the entity, not the reference to the entity in your iterator (list). Meaning

```
for price in prices:
    price = 1
```

would **not** change your original iterable object.

Does that somehow answer your question?

Comment: It clears up some confusion, I'm sure the rest I'll come to understand with more time. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You may accept this answer if it indeed contributed to your understanding. Thank you as well

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops are special syntax for dealing with iterators in a `while` loop. Python could do away with them entirely, forcing you to write

```
itr = iter(prices)
total = 0
while True:
    try:
        price = next(itr)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    total += price
del itr
```

so it should be clear why the `for` syntax is not in danger of being removed from the language :)

`iter(prices)` produces a special value that, when passed to `next`, produces a *different* element of `prices` on each call. So the first call to `next(itr)` returns `250`, the second `20`, and the third `30`. The *fourth* call, noting that it has reached the end of `prices`, raises a `StopIteration` exception instead, which the `try` statement catches in order to terminate the loop.